# Why does the fantasy land spec require that chain must return a value of the same Chain?

Tags: javascript, types, functional-programming, monads, fantasyland

> **`chain` method**
>
> A value which has a Chain must provide a `chain` method. The chain
>   method takes one argument:
>
> `m.chain(f)`
>
> 1. `f` must be a function which returns a value
>
>    - If `f` is not a function, the behaviour of `chain` is unspecified.
>    - `f` must return a value of the same Chain
> 2. `chain` must return a value of the same Chain

[GitHub - fantasyland](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#chain)

Given is a simple implementation of the option monad:

```
// prototypes:
const someProto = {
  of(x) { return some(x) },
  map(f) { return some(f(this.x)) },
  ap(ftor) { return ftor.map(this.x) },
  join() { return this.x },
  chain(mf) { return this.map(mf).join() }
};

const noneProto = {
  of() { return this },
  map() { return this },
  ap() { return this },
  join() { return this },
  chain() { return this }
};

// factories:
function some(x) {
  return Object.assign(Object.create(someProto), {x: x});
}

function none() {
  return Object.assign(Object.create(noneProto), {x: null});
}
```

To guarantee that `chain` always returns an option monad, I'd have to ensure that `mf` (monadic function) always returns one. This isn't possible, because `mf` is not part of the implementation. Rather it's defined when the monad is used:

```
// auxiliary function:
const sub = y => x => x - y;

let a = some(2);
let b = some(3);

a.chain(x => b.chain(y => some(sub(x)(y)))); // {x: 1}
a.chain(x => b.chain(y => sub(x)(y))); // 1 - ouch!
```

In the second method application the passed function returns no monad, which leads to an unwrapped result of the monadic computation. I could add a type check to `chain` or `join` maybe by duck typing, to solve the issue - that would be pretty ugly though.

Why does the specification require type safety exactly at this point? Javascript is dynamically typed and I would prefer to write appropriate unit tests instead of performing type checks at run-time. Would I violate the specification then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second example you should use **.map()**:

```
a.chain(x => b.map(y => sub(x)(y)));
```

and then everything follows the rules.

For comparison here are the equivalent Haskell signatures:

```
fmap  :: m a -> (a ->   b)   -> m b    -- same as .map()
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b)   -> m b    -- same as .chain()
```

So if your function returns a monadic value, use `.chain()`. Otherwise use `.map()`.

Comment: The problem is when someone misuses this option implementation in a way I did in my second example, it violates the spec. Thus my implementation might not be compliant with fantasy land. The only way to prevent this seems to consists in adding a type check at run-time. I believe that this is kind of ugly.

Comment: Your implementation of an Option monad is compatible with the spec. Your use of `.chain()` is not. Users of your Chainable are expected to use the appropriate method - either `.chain()` or `.map()` depending on what function they are supplying.

Comment: OK, I am not fully convinced but accept the answer, thanks!

Comment: I think it totally makes sense. Users also have a responsability. You can go buy a car and do an accident 10 minutes later .. Or you can buy a car and use it carefully for 20 years.